# magento - Warning: require_once(app/Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, ajax, magento, syntax-error, require-once

Using ajax, I am posting to a php file with the following code. however I recieve the following error when trying to require app/Mage.php:

**Warning: require_once(app/Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

```
<?php
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

function getProductStockLevel() {
    $productId = 104;
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $qty = $product->getStockItem()->getQty();
    echo $stockLevel;
}
getProductStockLevel();
?>
```

Can anyone help, All i need this file to do is return the stock value based on the product ID?

Thanks

Comment: from where you are run this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ajax post might not get the correct path, try this instead:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, errors like "Warning: require_once(app/Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" mean that PHP is looking for the file in its includes path, but can't find anything.

Where is app/Mage.php located? (Please make a note of the path).

Now, open up php.ini. In Linux distributions, php.ini tends to be located at /etc/php.ini, but if you use something like MAMP or XAMPP, it will be located within the MAMP/XAMPP folders. I don't know where php.ini would be stored by default on Windows boxes.

After you open up php.ini, find this section (note: this is from my MAMP install, so your values may vary):

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"  
include_path =".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.45/lib/php"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
```

Make sure that the full path where Mage.php is located is listed in the include_path for your own personal environment. For example, if you keep your includes out of your web space (which is always a good idea, particularly if you have things like passwords in your includes) and if you use a Unix like operating system, you might want your include_path to look like this:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"  
include_path =".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.45/lib/php:/app/appName/"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
```